# OpenApi Swagger Documentation for Perl application

Tags: perl, swagger, openapi

We are trying to create a OpenAPI Specification for our project. The entire application and its API services are written in PERL. We are unable to create the API specification using PERL. We tried using modules like.

`use OpenAPI::Client;`
`use WWW::SwaggerClient;`
`use Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI;`

but we are clueless on how to proceed with. Can anyone help with a PERL code which creates a API specification of OpenAPI standard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use any of [these](https://nordicapis.com/7-open-source-openapi-documentation-generators/) tools ?

Comment: I have to do it programmatically using any technology. I don't know if these tools will help me in that.

Comment: Maybe this can help - [Creating REST APIs with Perl, Mojolicious and OpenAPI](https://dev.to/raigaurav/creating-rest-apis-with-perl-mojolicious-and-openapi-1bng)